# how to add a number to each character of a string

Tags: c, string, function

I have to code a function in C which which receives a string of characters and then adds to each character the number 13. I've come up with this solution :

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() 
{
     char text[100];
     gets(text);
     code (text);
     }

 code (char text[100])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=98;i++)
    {
        text[i]=text[i] + 13 ;
    }
    printf ("%s",text);
    return (0);

}
```

Is this right?

Comment: _Is this right?_ Did you test it ? If it works, i suppose it's okay.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @reggaeguitar No it isn't. Code Review is for stuff that works and that is wanted to be made cleaner. Not for "Is this right?" / "Does this work?"

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought the op would benefit from knowing about codereview.stackexchange and might get some more helpful feedback without getting downvoted by posting there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need look some details:

```
// a void function should NOT return

void code (char text[]){
// when passing a string as argument, you don't need to indicate its' size

    int i = 0; // pay attention to give a value when initializing

    while (text[i] != '\0') { // '\0' indicates string's end...

        // while not the end
        text[i] += 13;    // same as text[i] = text[i] + 13;
        i += 1;           // same as i = i + 1;

    }

    printf("%s", text);
    // the string was encoded
}
```

---

Example:

```
char text[100];  // its' size is 100, but..
gets(text);      // if you read "hello" from input/keyboard
```

the result will be:

```
value ->        h  e  l  l  o  \0 
                |  |  |  |  |   |
position ->     0  1  2  3  4   5  ....
```

Your text ends in position 5.... because that, you need search for '\0', to find where the string ends..

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why not `for ( int i = 0; text[i]; i++ ) text[i] += 13;` or even `for ( int i = 0; text[i]; text[i++] += 13 );`?

Comment: @i486... yes, you can!! I didn't know about that... but I tried here and it works: _http://ideone.com/QWxaFz_ when the char contains '\0' it returns false

Comment: In fact, "false" is zero in C and '\0' is zero too.

Answer (score 0):

`code` function should have a return type, if it does not require to return anything, set its type to `void`.
 A function prototype/definition should be present before you use it. 
The user may not necessarily input a string of a fixed length, so use the `strlen` function from the `string.h` header file to calculate the legth of input string.
 The standard definition of `main()` should be as `int main(){ return 0;}`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void code(char []);
int main()
{
    char text[100];
    gets(text);
    code (text);
    return 0;
}

void code (char text[100])
{
    int i;
    int length=strlen(text);
    for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        text[i]=text[i] + 13 ;
    }
    printf ("%s",text);
    //return (0);
}
```